# Algebra: Unital Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I posted this earlier to no avail. It's an example of a topic i'm struggling with, I'm mostly looking for a sample answer that i can ask about and analyze to try and understand the "characteristic" portion.

$1$) Suppose $Y^3 = Y$ for each element $Y$ of a unital ring $R$. Show that $R$ has a finite characteristic d that is a divisor of $6$.

Comment: Take $Y=X+X.\ \ $

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: $2^3=2$ so $6=0$...

Comment: I also don't understand that

Comment: yeah sorry that would have been

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(Y+Y) \in R$ and $(Y+Y)^3=(Y+Y) \implies 8Y^3=2Y$. But $Y^3=Y$ and so, $6Y=0$ for all $Y$. So the characteristic is finite and must divide $6.$

I am just expanding the idea proposed @Mathematicos Chibchas.

Comment: i don't understand 6.Y=0 ?

Comment: @MJohn: I added more explanations

Comment: thank you (character limit)

Comment: Any chance you can define characterisic for me?

Comment: @MJohn Did it never occur to you to use a resource such as wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29

Comment: wiki is notoriously bad at sorting good and worthless information on their math pages. so no.

Comment: @MJohn: The above definition of characteristic in wiki is correct. Also, I can't write it as well as it's written over there.

Comment: @MJohn Wiki is bad at _explaining_ advanced mathematical concepts helpfully, but it's perfectly good at providing definitions.

Comment: @G.H.Faust I suppose you are correct. thank you all!